# Writing other color spaces than RGB in hex

Tags: ios, mobile-application, code, representation

I'm working on an iphone application that is going to feature a custom color selection tool. The application supports various color spaces and I'd like to use hex because the codes are shorter and more convient to type on an iphone.

So here's the problem: I know a 6 digit hex code *can* be used to store any sequence of 3 integers in the 0-255, but *should* it be used for that?

I've never seen hex used for anything but RGB and I'd like to know if I'd be infringing some unspoken rule if I used it for HSV, HSL, and YIQ.

I do not want to mess with conventions or standards but I also want a convienient text representation that's suitable for a user-base of designers and artists.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are against RGB? It's just that RGB unlike hex is easy to understand for an average user.

Comment: @IvanVenediktov Good question. I do like rgb, but these other color spaces are valuable to my app  because they allow for things like hue rotation for example.I'm worried that using RGB in the hex code could be confusing if the component sliders in my app are set to a different color space.

Comment: Would you coincided allowing multiple color models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, You definitely should not use hex for anything other than 24bit RGB or 32bit RGBA.

Hex notation is displayed in image editors entirely for convenience when its being used alongside web/software development, e.g. editing of CSS files. In those situations, hex notation is always RGB colorspace.

Even if that wasn't the case, hex notation is not going to make anyones lives easier for other colorspaces. HSV/HSL has the hue typically ranging from 0 to 360 degrees, and S and L/V often scales from 0 to 100%. It is definitely not convenient for anyone to have to mentally map that into a 0-255 range, with different scale factors for different components.

You should definitely keep hex input restricted to RGB only, and still allow people to enter RGB colors with the traditional 0-255 scales as well. There is a sadly a large amount of people who despite working with color on computers, don't understand the RGB->hex mapping and still need the computer is decode it for them.